# IPA Transcription help

Tags: vowels, ipa, transcription, rhoticity

I'm a linguistics student and working on narrow transcriptions.
Most transcription come fairly easily to me, but I'm caught up on the vowel in the word "hard"

How should the vowel be transcribed with General American (from central New York state) accent? 
What I have so far (with V standing in for the vowel: [hVɹd] (the vowel will presumably be rhoticisized)

Comment: English comes in many varieties and this particular vowel is one which varies across them, even within north American varieties. You really need to include information about which varieties you are interested in. You presume incorrectly otherwise since this vowel is not rhotacized in my own variety nor in Australia, Boston, England, New Zealand, and possibly New York. I think it is rhotacized in most varieties of Ireland, North America, and Scotland. Other varieties I'm too ignorant of. There are many.

Comment: There can be no right answer to this. A narrow transcription is one that includes pronunciation details that don't change what the word is in the dialect you're recording. There are many, many, many such details -- you can't possibly include them all. If you're making this transcription for your own work, you'd include only the details you wanted to focus on. In the context of a course, you'll need to include the details that your prof wants you to focus on. Either way, we on Stack Exchange have no way of knowing what those details are.

Comment: Well spotted @KevinRussell! How can you ask us to provide a *narrow* transcription of a vowel you describe in the *broadest* possible terms?

Comment: Oh boy that was an intensely rookie mistake. Edited.

Comment: For GenAm, Wiktionary goes with `/hɑɹd/`. Now as a dictionary that should be a broad transcription but I don't fully trust Wiktionary for consistency or conformity when it comes to IPA. I do think it's right in this case though. I'm no expert in New York English varieties. I think there are both rhotic and non-rhotic ones there. Let's see if we have an expert who can give you a narrower transcription if one is needed.